# Azure Cognitive Search - No results using wildcards on content with DOT

Tags: azure, lucene, tokenize, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Azure Cognitive Search to build a rich search experience inside a web application, however I'm facing the following issue: a field of the index will contains codes like "**Z.A.01.12**", "**A.A.44.11**" and so on...I'm trying to use the wildcards * as suffix in order to search all the results that starts with the value Z.A (just an example).

```
"Z.A.01.12" -> Z.A* => No results found. 
"Z.A.01.12" -> Z.A.* => No results found. 
"Z.A.01.12" -> Z\.A* => No results found.
```

I have tried different analyzer (**standard lucene**, **en.microsoft**, **whitespace** and **keyword**), but also when I see that exists only one token produced (for example with whitespace) with the entire content, when I query the service using wildlcard I receive "No results found".
I have already set **queryType=full** and *searchMode=any*. Furthermore I also tried to escape the . with "", but the results is always empty. Is there anything I can do to manage these cases?

Comment: It should be `Z\.A.*` or `Z[.]A.*` If this does not work, the regex is not parsed as such in your code.

Comment: You can try using an instance of Azure Cognitive Search. It doesn't work with your proposal